# npm installs dependencies in a wrong dir

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I created a node project that has a workspace, the project structure looks like:

/package.json

```
{
 "name": "root",
  "workspaces": ["./child"]
}
```

/child/package.json

```
{
  "name": "child",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "^13.1.2"
  }
}
```

when running `npm install` it installs `@angular/compiler` in the root node_modules dir which is the expected behavior.
but it installs `@angular/router` in child/node_modules, it should be installed in the root node_modules

also, the dependencies of it such as `rxjs` are installed in the child dir even no other versions of the same packages

the project is created in a clean and empty folder, and I cleared the npm cache

[minimal reproduction](https://github.com/eng-dibo/issue-npm-install)

Comment: Are you sure, you didn't run `npm install @angular/router` from within the `child` folder? It seems rather strange, that npm would install 1 package in the correct folder, but all others in a different folder ...

Comment: I run `npm install` only from the root dir